# Showing a subprocess-bitmap as bmp, using Content-Type in a Python server environment

Tags: python

I'm working on a service for a little sparetime project. I have a number of small Python-scripts, which are located in a subfolder. Their job is to generate a bitmap and return it.

On the same computer, I have a little server running (see code below). The job of this code is to run the appropriate script (which works) but also to take the result and show it with a header: **Content-Type: image/bmp**

This way, I can transfer the ID of the correct script to run by calling an URL like **myservername:8000/ac746b9cf**

I use routing and Flask. Most of the less important code has been omitted.

My problem is that I cannot get the bitmaps to be passed back as an image and displayed in the browser.

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import os
import json
import subprocess
from wand.image import Image

subprocesses = Flask(__name__)

@subprocesses.route('/<unitid>')
def get_product(unitid):
    # code omitted
    print("Create the image on-the-fly now")
    # Create the URL for the script now, based on a JSON-file
    thisSubprocess = ".\\program\\subprocesses\\"+subprocesses["subprocessid"]+"\\main\\main.py"
    # Call the script
    image = subprocess.run(["python", thisSubprocess]) # This is probably not the right way
                
    # Have a response set as Content-Type of BMP
    response = make_response(image) # I know this will not work, as it is of the wrong type
    
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'image/bmp')
    return response
    # code omitted

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(subprocesses, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

The scripts, called by the code above looks something like this:

```
import subprocess
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps, Image, BmpImagePlugin

# code omitted
w, h = 800, 600 # Image dimensions
img = Image.open("./program/subprocess/d535cf554ea66fbebfc415ac837a5828/main/template.png")
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
# code omitted
        
new_image = Image.new('RGB',(800,600), (255,255,255)) # P = 8-bit indexed
new_image.paste(img,(0,0))    
new_image.show() # The image should not show up on the screen, but be returned to the caller.
```

I also looked at the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html - I don't understand half of it, but it states that I should be able to connect to the output of the subprocess. I'm very much in doubt if I'm on the right track here, but a push in the right direction will be appreciated.